# Template pattern but with one of the classes not implementing the method

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to implement Template method pattern, but I need a slight variation that I don't think is best practice.
I have the following structure of classes

```
abstract class AbsClass {
    public void algorithm(){
        step1();
        step2();
    }
    private void step1() {
        //implementation
    }

    protected abstract void step2();
}

class A extends AbsClass {
    protected void step2() {
        // With implementation
    }
}

class B extends AbsClass {
    protected void step2() {
        // No implementation needed
    }
}
```

In the real case I have like 4 classes, and one of them doesn't need to have implementation for the second step. I don't think to leave the method empty would be good practice. I was thinking to put a comment(saying there is no need for implementation) in it, but I don't this would be the right solution.
Is there another approach I am not seeing?

Comment: is it necessary to make `step2` method an abstract method in `AbsClass`?

Comment: If its not abstract in the abstract class then it will have to have empty implementation there

Comment: @D.Tomov Can you attach real hierarchy of objects?

Comment: I suggest do not force a design pattern, Refer. my answer for details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571653/504133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [@Vinay Avasthi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5520794/vinay-avasthi)'s answer but I want to reinforce it.

## Hook Method

*Hook methods* are defined in the base class and are a default implementation. And these *can* be overridden - they don't have to.

From [Template-Method-Pattern Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) page:

> Template method's abstract class may also define hook methods that may be overridden by subclasses. These have a no-op implementation in the abstract class, but provide a "hook" on which to "hang" implementations.

## Improvement

What you should do is leave a comment in the method body like `// empty method body` so that someone reading your code (and maybe your self) knows that this method has not been forgotten

### Java's Default Methods

There is a second way to implement the Template-Method-Pattern in Java. Since Java 8 it is possible to have default method implementations in an interface.

If your methods do not depend on state it could look like:

```java
interface AbsClass {

  default void algorithm(){
    step1();
    step2();
  }

  default void step1() {
    // implementation or empty
  }

  default void step2() {
    // empty body in default case
  }
}

class B implements AbsClass { }
```

Comment: This is a much better explanation. Just as a side-note I saw that some code from the step above step2 could go into it (in the actual code). And now the method is not empty, it has 2 lines duplicating, but it is much more cohesive this way.

Comment: Having a default empty method in parent class forces the method in each of the sub class and if some class does not override and does not provide some implementation then again its like a method is forced in a class where it should not belong to.

Answer (score 5):

We should not *Force* a design pattern. Here if we prefer Composition over inheritance then its better.

The code present in the question we have a method defined in a class but actually method has no behavior.  Forcing a method in a class where it should not belomg to is not a good idea.

Below is one such possible implementation where you would not force a method to a class if it does not belong to it. Below is based on Strategy patter, but still I would say follow design principles and let the pattern itself suit your problem and do not force pattern to fit your solution.

```
public class AlgorithmClass {
    private Strategy strategy;
    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy){
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    public void algorithm(){
        step1();
        step2();
    }
    private void step1() {
        //implementation
    }

    private  void step2(){
        if(this.strategy != null){
              this.strategy.execute();
       }
    }
}

public interface Strategy{
    public void execute();
}

public class Strategy1 implements Strategy{
    public void execute(){
         //implement your one of the stategies for step 2
   }
}

public class Strategy2 implements Strategy{
    public void execute(){
         //implement your another stategy for step 2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is absolutely fine. If the default behavior of step2 is to do nothing, then you can have an empty method in base class and override in child classes.

Comment: If some one just puts a empty method so that in future code can be added to it still it is some what fine, **but forcing a method in a class which does not behavior corresponding to that method is a Poor practice**. Its even worst when both the abstract class and its sub classes are designed by same developer, (if using a library and extending an abstract class and then keepimg some method as empty is like a no option other than this, but in such a case developer knows he / she is following a bad practice and knowing it he / she does it with a reason ,hence its still acceptable )